# Script tags does not working in included html file

Tags: javascript, html, markdown, gist

I have a problem with using js scripts inside HTML files.
There are 2 HTML files ***a*** and ***b***. ***b*** is included inside ***a*** by using the script below.

```
function includeHTML() {
      var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
      z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
      for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
        elmnt = z[i];
        file = elmnt.getAttribute("w3-include-html");
        if (file) {
          xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4) {
              if (this.status == 200) {elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText;}
              if (this.status == 404) {elmnt.innerHTML = "Page not found.";}
              elmnt.removeAttribute("w3-include-html");
              includeHTML();
            }
          }
          xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
          xhttp.send();
          /* Exit the function: */
          return;
        }
      }
    }
```

I took it from w3school.com, using for include HTML, and my HTML file ***a*** and ***b*** is shown below:

***a.html***:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
     <div w3-include-html="b.html"></div>
     <script>
          includeHTML();
     </script>

</body>

</html>
```

And the ***b.html*** file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<h4>The gist enbed link:</h3>

<script src="https://gist.github.com/meminb/8e2488a47bacc7e93e645022d3dc3af1.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

I am expecting to be able to see the gist that I have embedded with script tags in the ***a.html*** file but it does not work. Is there any point I am missing to achieve this, or any other solution to be able to run script tags in included files?

Comment: So where is the script actually added to the page. I see you calling the method. I do not see the method anywhere on the page.

Comment: you need to include the definition of the function in both pages if you want to use it in both pages.  If not, you are calling the function from `a.html` so you need to include the definition of the function in that page

Comment: Next thing you will find out is `<script>` elements do not execute with innerHTML.

Comment: includeHTML()  function added some other place but it is working well, it is not the problem. I can see the result of this function except for other scripts inside included HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function includeHTML() {
        var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
        z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
        for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
            elmnt = z[i];
            file = elmnt.getAttribute("w3-include-html");
            if (file) {
                var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                iframe.style.cssText = 'border:none;width:100%;height:100%;';
                iframe.src = file;
                elmnt.removeAttribute("w3-include-html");
                elmnt.appendChild(iframe);
                setTimeout((f, e) => {
                    var body = f.contentWindow.document.body;
                    var html = f.contentWindow.document.documentElement;
                    var height = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
                    // console.log(e);
                    e.style.height = height + 'px';
                    // console.log(height);
                }, 500, iframe, elmnt);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is not even working for including other tags:(